# Using Xcode URL Types

Tags: ios, xcode, url-scheme

I have an iOS app and am already using an API which ask me for a redirect URI for authentication purposes. I currently have one URL type in Xcode, with the following:

```
Identifier: com.APP_NAME
URL Schemes: APP_NAME
```

I'm now trying to import a new API, which asks me for a redirect URI with a URL scheme unique to this API, so I will create

```
URL Scheme: APP_NAME-API_NAME
```

My question is whether I need to create a new URL type as well for this new URL scheme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using a unique host part per API, i.e.:

API 1: your_url_scheme://api1

API 2: your_url_scheme://api2

If handleOpenURL is called you just need to check the host part of the url and call your logic depending on the current service

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple URI schemes as well. Different SDKs usually respect that you may have multiple SDKs installed and each expects to be able to uniquely make use of deeplinking. Here's an example of two SDK's being used in conjunction (actually, three really):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    if (![[Branch getInstance] handleDeepLink:url]) {
        // do other deep link routing for the Facebook SDK, Pinterest SDK, etc
    }
    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                        withSession:[PFFacebookUtils session]];
}
```